# Recompile cryptocurrency files for different platform

Tags: linux, compilation, xeon-phi

I'm trying to tweak some source files of a cryptonight-algorithm cryptocurrency so it can run on the linux uOS embedded on a xeon phi, but I am unsure how to compile when there are many different source files that make the one binary. Any ideas on how to use intel compilers to do this, or really any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Xeon Phi Quick Start Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-developers-quick-start-guide). There is a section that briefly describes native cross compiling. Under the ["Training tab"](https://software.intel.com/mic-developer) is a lot of good information on programming.

In general, using a multi-source build with libraries is no different than you'd normally do it for cross compiling. You need to make sure that your paths to libraries, etc, are set correctly on the Xeon Phi. Since you are natively executing, this should be no different than what you'd expect. Something to note if you are not externally mounting a file system with the correct libraries is that you need to explicitly copy over any libraries and make sure they are where your binary expects them. If you are working in a data center environment, your administrators have probably taken care of this.